# safari can't verify website certificate

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I upgraded my safari yesterday ever since I keep getting "Safari can't verify the website certificate" I have tried checking for any other software updates to no avail, I have done Keychain First Aid and this says there is no problems, can anyone help me please?

Comment: a specific web site or in general

Comment: Post a screenshot of the details ("Show certificate") box.